# Subview position on the parent view iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I m using a menu bar like this (using UIBUTTONS on an ImageView)

[image]

Now what I required to do is that when I click on each button a popover (subview) should come up like:

[image]

How can I do that?

My second question is that when i click on the same button or anywhere else on the view then the popover should get hide and if i click on another menu button popover should get hide from previous button and should be shown on other button...

My project is already created with UIviewcontroller, so i think it would be much difficult to include the tab bars

any help please ...

```
-(IBAction)buttonNotify:(id)sender{

popOver.frame = CGRectMake(173, 385, 88, 33);

[self.view addSubview:popOver];
```

}

Comment: working code would be good as I need to do it on urgent basis.... but if u would be able to give me idea, i am thankful for that too

Comment: no its for iPhone, popover word used for the view which will be popped up, well its done, Padavan and hiren443 has helped me a lot. Just the thing left is that how to hide the popupview/popup menu/subview by clicking anywhere on the screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In .h file of your ViewController declare

```
UIImageView *popupView`;
```

In .m file in initialisation initialise it, something like

```
popupView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:@"your_image.png"];
popUpView.frame = //some CGRect here//;
popUpView.hidden = YES;
[self.view addsubView:popupView];
[popupView release];
```

Also when you create your buttons you do it like this, yep?

```
UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
btn.frame = //some CGRect here//;
btn.tag = 1; // here you can set numeric tag for all your buttons
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonHandler:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:btn]; 
[btn release]
```

And implement method

```
-(void)buttonHandler:(id)sender
{
    //sender here is your button object
    //so you can take it's tag or frame or something else to set frame of popupView
    popUpView.frame = //some rect
    popUpView.hidden = NO;
}
```

And you when you handle touch on your view, set 
`popupView.hidden = YES` to hide it

Also you can add some animation.

Comment: Thanx @Padavan, and one more question please that if user clicks anywhere on view then how the popover will get hide ?

Comment: @OmerKhan There are many ways. For example, you can set self.view.multipleTouchEnabled=YES and implement method
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event // it will be called when you touch your view.

Comment: thank you dude ... its done.... just the second click on button does not hides the popup ... otherwise its working fine now

Comment: @OmerKhan It's easy. Just change popUpView.hidden = NO to popUpView.hidden = !popUpView.hidden in -(void)buttonHandler:(id)sender.

Comment: dude i have tried it but now it does even shows the popUpView even on one click ...

Answer (score 0):

```
    menu1Btn.tag = 0;
menu2Btn.tag = 1;
....


-(IBAction)buttonNotify:(id)sender{  
int tag = [sender tag];  
[popOver removeFromSuperView];  
if(tag ==0){  
popOver.frame = CGRectMake(0, 385, 88, 33);  
[self.view addSubview:popOver];  
}  
else if(tag ==1){
popOver.frame = CGRectMake(40, 385, 88, 33);  
[self.view addSubview:popOver];  

}
else if(tag ==2){
popOver.frame = CGRectMake(80, 385, 88, 33);  
[self.view addSubview:popOver];  

}
...... 

}
```

Comment: no it's so simple. you have to just managed bool and coordinate. if you don't want to managed extra bool then give the tag to every buttons and use this button tag to handle showing of popover view

Comment: have set the coordinates for a single button... i have edited my question and added code snippet